# How to make ListField in ModelSerializer DRF not mandatory

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want a field in my Django model that stores a list of strings (I don't want to use a related field for some reasons, only validate that user has sent a correct list).

I have it correctly working, the problem is that I'm not success to make this field not mandatory when updating the object via Django REST Framework.

This is my implementation, I have test some variations with the same result

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    hashtags = models.CharField(max_length=512, default=None, null=True, blank=True)

    @property
    def hashtags_as_list(self):
        """ Hashtags are stored on DB as a text json convert to object again
        """
        return json.loads(self.hashtags) if self.hashtags else None

    @hashtags_as_list.setter
    def hashtags_as_list(self, value):
        """ Hashtags are stored on DB as a text json of the list object
        """
        self.hashtags = json.dumps(value)

class SomeModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    hashtags = serializers.ListField(
        source='hashtags_as_list',
        default = [],
        required = False,
        child = serializers.CharField(min_length=3, max_length=32, required=False)
    )
```

I only get the error when I do PUT on the Browsable API, inspecting the query is sending hashtags blank.

```
------WebKitFormBoundary4L5MFBPrRA0QDqFL
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="hashtags"


------WebKitFormBoundary4L5MFBPrRA0QDqFL
```

And the error is as follows:

```
{
    "hashtags": [
        "This field may not be blank."
    ]
}
```

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: Have you tried adding `required=False`? [Docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#required) for reference.

Comment: I have added the error to the answer, also required=False that does nothing.

Comment: I have noticed that custom fields and "advanced" features such as a composite fields often don't work, at least right out with the browsable API. I'd suggest you test your endpoint with curl or a similar tool instead.

Comment: add `read_only=True`

Comment: The call works as expected Adrián, as you commented only fails in browsable API. read_only is not an option DhiaTN, I want this field to be editable.

Answer (score 2):

You are sending post data for `hashtags` except without content which is why DRF is returning that error message. You can fix that by using:

```
hashtags = serializers.ListField(required=False, child=CharField(allow_blank=True, ...), ...)
```

Please note however that you might need to adjust some of your code to handle when `hashtags` will normalize to empty string.

Comment: I get `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'allow_blank'`, I use quite updated DRF3.2.3

Comment: oh yea. Jus looked at code. `ListField` subclasses `Field` directly vs `CharField` which supports `allow_blank` field.

Comment: updated answer. try it now. just move the `allow_blank=True` to the child definition. that should either work or give you another error. I cant test it now so dont know for sure.

Comment: With this solution, when the field is left empty it creates an array with an empty string `"hashtags": [""]`, in fact any string I put is set as the first element of the list, it seems a problem of DRF browsable API with ListFields, may be the best solution would have been to omit them from the form.